# ANDEngine ADmob AD not visible

Tags: android, admob, andengine

I am trying to show adMob Ads in my game made in AndEngine.

I am able to get WebViewResponse against my WebRequest in LogCat, plus when I remove network permission, i am getting a black box with network requirement error. but when I add the network requirement the web response is received but no success in displaying it.

What could be the problem, I am making?

Thanks.

```
@Override
protected void onSetContentView() {


    final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutLayoutParams =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                         FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, “xxxxxxxxx”);

    adView.refreshDrawableState();
    adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams adViewLayoutParams =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                         FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                         Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50,
            getResources ().getDisplayMetrics ());
    // top of AD is at middle of the screen
    adViewLayoutParams.topMargin = height/2;
    Log.v("AD", "Adview height : " + height);
    Log.v("AD", "Adview size {x:" + adView.getWidth() + ", y: " + adView.getHeight()+ "}");
    adView.setAlpha(255);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.addTestDevice( AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    adRequest.addTestDevice(“xxxxxxxxxxxxxx”);
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
    mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(mEngine, this);

    final android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(super.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams());

    frameLayout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView, surfaceViewLayoutParams);
    frameLayout.addView(adView, adViewLayoutParams);

    this.setContentView(frameLayout, frameLayoutLayoutParams);
}
```

Comment: What does logcat say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problems with an older version of admob sdk GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.1.0. But moving to a new one (at least)4.3.1 resolved the problem. Could you please try the latest sdk and then execute the same function? hope it helps.